# c# Invalid token 'while' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (while loop not working)

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I'm new to c# but quite familiar with c, this error however doesn't make much sense to me, as I have specifically followed the required syntax shown on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int years = 1;
    while (years <=10) {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(bushels1.Text);
        numericUpDown1.Maximum = value;
    }

    private void bushels1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void nextYear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: `while` is used inside methods, you are trying to use it on class level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `while` directly inside the class, it should be part of a method, You can't write statements like `while` directly inside the class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int years = 1;
    while (years <=10) {
   //^^
```

It should be part of method like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int years = 1;
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
       while (years <=10) {
      //rest of your code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your while loop must be in a method, you have it in the variable/method declaration area.  Remove it and place inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

You have a "while (years <=10) {" line that is not inside a function, near the top. That definitely is not going to work. What are you expecting it to do?

You say you're familiar with c, but think about it - would you expect a while {} construct to work at the class level in c, either? (It would not. Loops only work inside functions, in most languages, including C#.)